# Program stops responding after a class member function?

Tags: c++, class, function

```
int main() {

    one.print(two, three);
        cout << "HERE" << endl;
    calculate(3, 1, 2, 3);
    one.~tower();
    two.~tower();
    three.~tower();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Hello everybody. I am making a program (in c++) that prints out the solution to the tower of Hanoi puzzle. So I have this function called print, and it works great, but then for some reason it doesn't return to main() afterwards.

So after `one.print(two, three)` no further commands in main are executed. I know because I did a test with `cout` . However, all the commands in the function are executed flawlessly. Here is the function.

```
void tower::print(tower two, tower three) {

for(int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
    checkandprint(levels[i], no);
    checkandprint(two.levels[i], no);
    checkandprint(three.levels[i], no);
    cout << endl;   
}

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    bottoms(no);
}
cout << "Press enter to continue...";
cin.get();
cout << "here (end of function)" << endl;
}
```

and here is the prototype of that function in the `tower` class:

```
class tower {
public:
    int no;
    int *levels;
    tower(int init, bool source);
    ~tower() {int *r = &no; delete r; delete [] levels;}
    void print(tower two, tower three); //this one!
    void bottoms(int rows);
    void assign(int n);
    void move(int dest);
```

};

any ideas?

Comment: You mean as to what language you're using?  I'd guess Java.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Oh I'm using c++. but my question was regarding why the program stops working after the function.

Comment: Actuall, I suppose C is a better guess.

Comment: It stops working because you don't have any output statements anywhere to show where it's getting.  And because you (apparently) have no implementation of `calculate`.

Comment: yeah sorry for the confusion

Comment: what do you mean by output statements?

Comment: Does c++ flush standard out automatically? Otherwise it might crash after the line you mention, but the output is just not shown on the screen yet.

Comment: no I do have a definition for calculate its just not in the code sample that I posted. (the statement is program is quite long, I didn't want to post it all)

Comment: Please learn the basics, then move on to OOP, you're seriously making some big confusions and mistakes, like explicitly calling the destructor.

Comment: well isn't the destructor OOP?

Comment: @user2457666, You shouldn't even define your own destructor, nor call it. Make `levels` a `std::vector`.

Comment: It would be really nice, too, if you're going to make text-based programs, to find a real environment where you don't have to use this `Press enter to continue` and `system("PAUSE");` garbage, that makes my eyes water every time I see it.

Comment: yeah I was thinking the same thing! do you have any ideas about alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~tower() {
    int *r = &no; delete r; // <- this is wrong
    delete [] levels;
}
```

You didn't allocate separate space for `int no`, so you shouldn't be deleting it. The memory for it is included in the memory for the `tower` object itself, it'll be freed when the `tower` is freed, you don't have to worry about it.

When the `print` function returns, the two `tower` objects `two` and `three` will be destroyed and their destructors will be called. When they try to delete a pointer to `no`, which they didn't allocate, your program will incur in undefined behaviour, meaning that anything can happen at that point. Luckily, all that happened to you was that the program crashed, but I've seen worse things happen... http://xkcd.com/292/

Also note that there might still be other problems with your destructor, depending on how you're allocating and/or copying the `levels` array, specially when passing `tower` by value to `print`. You'd be better off using a `std::vector<int> levels` instead, and then you don't have to worry about allocating or deleting it.

Oh, and yeah, like people mentioned in the comments, you don't do this:

```
one.~tower(); // bad, very very bad and wrong,
              // just wrong, bad and wrong, and awful, just...
              // just don't do it, ok?
```

the destructor is called by the program when the object is destroyed: when you explicitly `delete` an object that you allocated yourself, or when the lifetime of an object ends, like when a function returns and all the local objects are destroyed (which is what happens to the arguments of `print`, `tower two` and `tower three`, when `print` returns).

Comment: thanks for the advice-- I was never completely clear on what to write in a destructor, or whether I needed to call it.